# How to fill a tag with remaining width in html?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make in 1 line, an input and two buttons. The two button's width should wrap the content, and then the input should fill the width of its parent. This is what I have currently

```
        <input id="input-field" style="display:inline-block; width:60%;"></input>
        <button id="sticker-button" style="display:inline-block;">☺</button>
        <button id="send-button" style="display:inline-block;">➤</button>
```

But I can't find the css to make a input tag fill the remaining width. Currently I just put 60%, but this clearly does not work. Like if this was android, I would have the buttons width be `wrap_content` and the input's width be `fill_parent`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this

```
        <div style="display:flex;">
            <input id="input-field" style="width:100%;"></input>
            <button id="sticker-button">☺</button>
            <button id="send-button">➤</button>
        </div>
```